# Angularjs binding not updating in http response call back before alert();

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to update the front end by changing scope variable value after http response .

The scope variable is updated correctly but event happens after the alert() even though alert is placed after the statement where i am updating scope variable :

```
if (data.status === "Success") {
    $scope.close = null;// close updates dom after next statement which is not expected .

    alert(data.successmessage);
}
```

Comment: That is completely expected. Why would you expect differently?

Comment: @georgeawg $scope.close variable closes a popup . so in this case after http response alert happens and then the popup closes . Is it possible that after the dom is updated and then alert () just like the statement line number  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it differently is to put the alert in a $timeout:

```
if (data.status === "Success") {
    $scope.close = null;// close updates dom after next statement which is not expected .

    $timeout(function() {
        alert(data.successmessage);
    });
}
```

That allows the browser to render the new DOM before doing the alert operation.

For more information, see

- [AngularJS $timeout Service API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout)